# Está dando este erro qdo tento add dados na tabela - 00928. 00000 - "missing SELECT keyword

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Está dando este erro qdo tento add dados na tabela - 00928. 00000 - "missing SELECT keyword

```
INSERT INTO DEPT
(
DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC)
VALUES
(10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');
(20, 'RESEARCH', 'DALLAS');
(30, 'SALES', 'CHICAGO');
(40, 'OPERATIONS', 'BOSTON');
```

Comment: use `,` para separar a lista de values e não `;`

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo...valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que está usando `;` como separador da lista de values, e o correto é usar `,` (vírgula).

O `;` nesse caso está funcionando como finalizador do comando, por isso ele da erro dizendo esperar um `SELECT` (*"missing SELECT keyword"*).

Veja a documentação: [https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-inserting-multiple-rows-of-data)

No seu exemplo, deve ser:

```
INSERT INTO DEPT ( DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC) VALUES 
(10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK'),
(20, 'RESEARCH', 'DALLAS'),
(30, 'SALES', 'CHICAGO'),
(40, 'OPERATIONS', 'BOSTON')
```